# From a point $P=(3,4)$, perpendiculars PQ and PR are drawn to line $3x+4y-7=0$ and a variable line $y-1=m(x-7)$ respectively

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

> From a point $P=(3,4)$, perpendiculars PQ and PR are drawn to line $3x+4y-7=0$ and a variable line $y-1=m(x-7)$ respectively, find the maximum area of $\triangle PQR$.

On [EduRev website](https://edurev.in/question/2462308/From-a-point-P--3--4--perpendiculars-PQ-and-PR-are), they have taken the point R to be $(7,1)$. Why? Can't the foot of the perpendicular be some other point?

On [toppr website](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/from-a-point-p34-perpendiculars-pq-and-pr-are-drawn-to-line-3x4y70-and-a/), they are taking general PR in terms of m. And then they say for maximum area, $PR=5$. For this, they are comparing the slope of PQ. That's more confusing.

Can anyone explain this? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, $R$ should depend on $m.$

Comment: Can you find $Q?$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, I can find Q

Comment: My inclination is to translate the question so that $P=(0,0).$ Writing $(x,y)=( u+3,v+4)$ you get two new equations for the lines. The perpendicular from $(0,0)$ to the line $au+bv+c=0$ is $(u,v)=\left(\frac{-ac}{a^2+b^2},\frac{-bc}{ a^2+b^2}\right).$

Comment: I think Q is coming out to be $(-\frac{39}5,-\frac{52}5)$

Comment: That's not what I get for $Q.$ The line doesn't even go into that quadrant of the $(x,y)$ plane - your $Q$ is not on the given line.

Comment: At least one of $x,y$ must be positive for $3x+4y=7.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry, I made a mistake. I think Q is $(\frac{21}{25},\frac{28}{25})$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Also, we may use translation. Also, another method is to let R in terms of m. We have P and Q. And then we can find the area of triangle and we can maximize it. But the method adopted by above listed websites is quite short. I wonder how they did it

Comment: EduRev didn't show you how to solve it, they just gave the answer.

Comment: @aarbee; Point Q$ =(\frac{21}{25},\frac{28}{25})$ is the correct answer yes. But the confusion arises when we consider a point $P(3,4)$, $Q$, and point R $(7,1)$. The area of this triangle does not yield $5$, but $6.15$ or something...

Comment: @aarbee; Are we certain that the correct answer is $5$?

Comment: The second answer makes an assumption that the area is $\frac12 PQ\times PR,$ which is only true if $PQ$ and $PR$ are perpendicular. Looks wrong, on the face.

Comment: In particular, the area is rational when $m$ is rational, since all the coordinates will be rational, but this is not true for the formula given by toppr. They are just wrong.

Comment: @Aristarchus_ the maximum area on both the websites is given to be $9$.

Comment: @Aristarchus_ area of the triangle with vertices $(3,4), (7,1),(\frac{21}{25},\frac{28}{25})$ is coming out to be $9$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews irrespective of the value of m, if R is $(7,1)$, area is coming out to be $9$

Comment: @aarbee Sure, but the answer at toppr says the area in terms of $m$ has a denominator of $\sqrt{m^2+1},$ which would not be rational for all rational $m.$ The fact that it is rational when toppr computes the maximum is (sort of) luck.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the perpendicular cannot be some other point is that the variable line, which can be rewritten as $$y = m \cdot (x-7) + 1$$, where m is the slope of the line has a fixed at a point $(7,1)$. As you can see from the coordinates of $x$ and $y$. From the elementary slope formula it follows...$y_{2} - y_{1} = a \cdot (x_{2} - x_{1})$  where $x_{1} = 7$ and $y_{1} =1$ here.

Considering this, If we take a look at the graphs of these functions...
[image].
We can calculate and see that the second answer cannot be true with both perpendiculars $PQ$ and $PR$ drawn to lines respectively. Finally $m$ must be $0.75$. The slope equation evaluates then to $0.75x - \frac {25}{3}$

Comment: I could see that $(7,1)$ lies on the line. My doubt was why this was supposed to be the foot of the perpendicular

Comment: The figure is not right. You have a line going through $C=(7,1)$, and $R$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $P$ to this line. In most cases $C\ne R$

Comment: @aarbee; it is the point of intersection of the variable line and the perpendicular from the point P

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understand the problem setup:

[image: picture]

Point $P(3,4)$ is given. point $Q$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $P$ to $3x+4y−7=0$. That means that the slope of $PQ$ is $4/3$. Since $PQ$ goes through $P$, the equation of that line is $$y=\frac43 x$$
Then point $Q$ is at the intersection of the two lines, so $$\begin{cases}y_Q=\frac43x_Q\\3x_Q+4y_Q-7=0\end{cases}$$
From here $$x_Q=\frac{21}{25}\\y_Q=\frac{28}{25}$$
The second line goes through point $A(7,1)$, and has the equation $$y=mx-7m+1$$
The slope of this line is $m$, so the slope of perpendicular to the line is $-1/m$. $R$ is the foot of the perpendicular from $P$. Then the equation of $PR$ line is $$y-y_P=-\frac 1m(x-x_P)\\y=-\frac1m x+\frac3m+4$$
Then $R$ is at the intersection, so $$\begin{cases}y_R=-\frac1m x_R+\frac3m+4\\y_R=mx_R-7m+1\end{cases}$$
I will let you calculate $x_R$ and $y_R$, both are some functions of $m$. Then, the area of $\triangle PQR$ is given by the half of length of $PQ$ (which is a constant) multiplied by the distance ($h$) from $R$ to the $PQ$ line. This is given by $$h=\frac{|-4x_R+3y_R|}{\sqrt{4^2+3^2}}$$
Find the maximum of $h$, then find the desired area.